# Capybara-webkit tries to open example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using capybara, capybara-webkit, capybara-screenshot together with cucumber. (Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.1.3) and `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` is also set env.rb

Unfortunately running a cucumber spec with `@javascript` will never succeed for some reason and the error screenshots just capture example.com.

The URL which I actually try to open is generated with a rails router result for one of my models e.g. with `visit products_url`

So how can I avoid that it ends up querying example.com?

Any input is very welcome.

---

Just because the comment is messed up - here's what I found was the solution:

```
Capybara.run_server = true
Capybara.server_port = 7787
Before '@javascript' do
  Capybara.app_host = "http://127.0.0.1:#{Capybara.server_port}"
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `visit products_path` instead. They do not recommend using absolute URLs in "Gotchas" section of [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

Comment: Using products_path ends with an error in the first place:

Unable to load URL: file:///products (Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError)

But once I also configure the app_host it starts working. So that's my current configuration:


Capybara.run_server = true
Capybara.server_port = 7787
Before '@javascript' do
  Capybara.app_host = "http://127.0.0.1:#{Capybara.server_port}"
end

In addition this: http://www.emmanueloga.com/2011/07/26/taming-a-capybara.html seesm to resolve some other pitfalls with capybara and rails 3.1

Comment: Seems the gotchas does not apply to Webkit when talking about absolute URLs

Answer (score 1):

For me, there was a much sneaker "gotcha" (and I was using Capybara with Rspec). Originally in a spec I had:

```
visit "foos/5"
```

This worked fine with `Rack::Test` but when I wanted to switch to the `webkit` driver to test js interactions, I got that exception (Unable to load URL: file:///products (Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError)).

What I had to do was change the path I passed to visit, like so:

```
visit "/foos/5"
```

Succes!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another potential gotcha, posted for others that might have this issue. I was testing action caching, and the key Rails generates looks like "views/www.example.com/products".  This happens even if you use products_path as the url. This can lead to the need to set your server name so you can know in advance what cache key to expect.