# Capybara current_url giving example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

A while ago I found this really useful Capybara tip about opening the current page as a human would see it midway through your tests:

> Find the Port Address and Pause the Test
>
> Sometimes I just want to see what's going on in the browser. Although save_and_open_page gives you some idea of what's going on, you can't really click around, because the page it gives you is static and lacking assets. To dig into what's going on, I like to use a trick I learned from my mentor, Mike Pack.
>
> Just above the broken line in your test, add these two lines of code. Note that you have to have pry installed in your current gemset or specified in the Gemfile for this to work.
>
> ```
> puts current_url
> require 'pry'; binding.pry
> ```
>
> Run the specs, and when they pause, copy the url and port number from the test output. Open your browser and paste the address into the window. Voila! You're now browsing your site in test mode!

(tip three from [here](https://quickleft.com/blog/five-capybara-hacks-to-make-your-testing-experience-less-painful/))

I remember this working straightforwardly, but now when I use it, the host is given as 'http://www.example.com/' and unsurprisingly trying to open it gets no-where.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620283/capybara-webkit-tries-to-open-example-com) which maybe contains enough info to figure out how to hack Capybara, but my first efforts hasn't worked I was wondering if anyone knew an out-of-the-boxish solution?

Our maybe-relevant testing gems are Capybara, Poltergeist, Launchy and Webmock.

Answer (score 1):

If current_url is returning as example.com then the test you're trying to do this on is most likely using the `rack_test` driver (no JS, very limited CSS). You can't point a browser at tests using the rack_test driver because it doesn't start up a server to serve the pages for those tests.